# Trying to write text in async task

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get data to text file in the background while other tests are running -

```
public void main()
{
  GetData()
  ...Starting tests.....
}
public async Task GetData()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        string path = "" + ResultsPath + "\\Telemes.txt";
        File.WriteAllText( Path , string.Join("," , Meas().Keys) + "\r\n");
        while(true)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path , string.Join(",", Meas().Values));   

            if(tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
        }});
}
```

Running it as a synchronous task works OK and get me all the data I need.
Calling it in this way doesn't create any text file at all, but the tests are going just fine.

I'm guessing I am not calling the task properly. Where is the mistake?

Comment: You never await for the task created by `GetData` to finish.  If this is a console application, it will terminate before the background thread created by `GetData` has a chance to start.

Comment: Does main last for a longer time? If main does little work it may exit before the task has a chance to run. It would be a good idea to wait the task before exiting so it has a chance to complete it's work.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code - first, it's not asynchronous. You are using a new thread to write *synchronously*. Second, you use the task as if it were a thread - you use an infinite loop to read and write data. A task is supposed to be a *single* execution. You don't even check the status of the task, so any exceptions are lost. For example, does `Meas()` return anything? Could it be null when the thread is first called?

Comment: A far better option would be to use one of the many publish/subscribe mechanisms offered by .NET to publish messages from the main thread to a background thread for processing. The simplest solution would be to use an [ActionBlock< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data). The documentation contains a logging example, similar to what this code seems to be doing

Comment: I'm getting new data consistently, this is why I'm using endless loop. The main thread is long task(few hours) while new data should flow every few seconds.

The question is how to make it write it while the main is running.

Comment: The endless loop is *only* required when using raw threads. Using global state, as the `Meas()` call shows here, requires synchronized access through locking. Tasks were created to avoid all this. A task represents a *single* execution. You pass the data you need when you create the task, thus avoiding concurrency issues.

Comment: Did you check the `ActinoBlock< T>` example? The entire logging code gets replaced by a single line and the occasional call to `Post`. Examples using `BlockingCollection< T>` or `ConcurrentQueue< T>` are a bit more involved. In all cases though, you don't try to read the state from inside the task. Your main thread posts a message to the queue or block, and whoever listens on the other side works with it. No loops or locks required

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the task in you main method. Something like below:

```
public async void main()
{
  Task getDataTask = GetData();
  ...Starting tests.....
  //Do something that is not dependent upon GetData()
  await getDataTask;
  //Processing completed
  Console.Write("File GetData - complete");
}
```

Note: To be able to use await, your main() method should also be async!